# 'bash' : no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, windows, bash, ubuntu

I just joined the windows insider program so I could install Ubuntu and install Ruby via bash commands. Everytime I open the the ubuntu command prompt it will not allow me to run any commands without throwing errors. examples

Command 'sudo' is not availiable in '/usr/bin/sudo'

At the top of the Ubuntu command prompt it says:
/usr/bin/env: 'bash': no such file or directory

How can I resolve this issue. I need to set up ruby so I can start developing.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might have better luck just using Ubuntu inside of VirtualBox, or something. Mixing Windows in makes everything a little more difficult, which can be frustrating while learning.

Comment: This all sounds very strange. You don't have to join windows' insider program anymore to use the windows subsystem for linux (WSL) . Have you installed Ubuntu on `C:`? [As it seems](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/wsl/install-win10), WSL only works from there. Is the WSL enabled? Did you interrupt the actual installation of ubuntu (runs when you open the terminal for the first time)?

Comment: Did you set your PATH variable? linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Comment: [Install Ruby On Rails on Windows 10](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check content of PATH variable by executing command $ echo $PATH

If you do not find /usr/bin in the output than you can append /usr/bin in PATH variable by executing command

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```